# Bootstrap Modal instead of jQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a custom php script that uses jQuery Dialog for confirmation diaglog boxes.

The js that initates the dialog looks like this:

```
    (function ($) {
    $(function () {
        if ($('#frmCreateUser').length > 0) {
            $('#frmCreateUser').validate();
        }
        if ($('#frmUpdateUser').length > 0) {
            $('#frmUpdateUser').validate();
        }

        $("a.icon-delete").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#record_id').text($(this).attr('rev'));
            $('#dialogDelete').dialog('open');
        });

        if ($("#tabs").length > 0) {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                select: function(event, ui){
                    $("#message_box").html("");
                    switch(ui.index){
                        case 0:
                            $("#info_list_box").css("display", "block");
                            $("#info_add_box").css("display", "none");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            $("#info_list_box").css("display", "none");
                            $("#info_add_box").css("display", "block");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        $(".multiselect").multiselect({
            minWidth: 400
        });
        if ($("#dialogDelete").length > 0) {
            $("#dialogDelete").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                height:220,
                modal: true,
                close: function(){
                    $('#record_id').text('');
                },
                buttons: {
                    'Delete': function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                id: $('#record_id').text()
                            },
                            url: "index.php?controller=AdminUsers&action=delete",
                            success: function (res) {
                                $("#content").html(res);
                                $("#tabs").tabs();
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).dialog('close');            
                    },
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have done serval modifications for replacing it with Bootstrap modal, so at this moment it looks like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        if ($('#frmCreateUser').length > 0) {
            $('#frmCreateUser').validate();
        }
        if ($('#frmUpdateUser').length > 0) {
            $('#frmUpdateUser').validate();
        }

        $("a.icon-delete").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#record_id').text($(this).attr('rev'));
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });

        if ($("#tabs").length > 0) {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                select: function(event, ui){
                    $("#message_box").html("");
                    switch(ui.index){
                        case 0:
                            $("#info_list_box").css("display", "block");
                            $("#info_add_box").css("display", "none");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            $("#info_list_box").css("display", "none");
                            $("#info_add_box").css("display", "block");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        $(".multiselect").multiselect({
            minWidth: 400
        });
        if ($("#myModal").length > 0) {
            $("#myModal").modal({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                height:220,
                modal: true,
                close: function(){
                    $('#record_id').text('');
                },
                buttons: {
                    'Delete': function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                id: $('#record_id').text()
                            },
                            url: "index.php?controller=AdminUsers&action=delete",
                            success: function (res) {
                                $("#content").html(res);
                                $("#tabs").tabs();
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).modal('hide');          
                    },
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).modal('hide');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

It seems that it has helped, and the dialog is now a modal as desired, though my buttons is not working.. i have made sure that the buttons have the role of button, but the js is not using my buttons as in the Dialog box.. im pretty sure that the error is somewhere around the last time the #myModal id is used..

Thank you.

Comment: Try surrounding the JS with `$(document).ready(code goes here);`

Comment: @TrevorHutto `$(function(){` is short hand for that.

Comment: you dont need to put a self executing function wrapped around the document on ready function, i would definitely take out that self executing function

Comment: A php script that uses JQuery?

Comment: @No1_Melman what function is you talking about? the first one?
If i remove the first function, the script will delete the item without asking for confirmation - meaning it will not fire the script

Comment: @Pinoniq yes? why not? - this is by the way a customized script i bought some years ago .. is it recommended not to use js and php together?

Comment: In your second code snippet, starting from this line `$(".multiselect").multiselect({` - I guess the `if` operator should be after `});` - copy&paste error?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin this was just a error in here, thank you for making me aware so i can edit it in here.. i have swapped those lines by accident when i was going to make the 2nd snippet. In the file they are like edited.

Comment: @SolidSnake PHP is server side an JS is client side...

Comment: @Pinoniq i really dont see why that should be a reason not to use both? the script is a customized simple cms that writes and pulls from database as well.. this is just a js from the script im trying to modify..

Comment: @SolidSnake the self executing function is the `(function ($) {})(jQuery);`, it shouldn't be needed, I've implemented both jQuery modals and Bootstrap modals, with and without knockout js and never had a self executing function surround the jQuery on load event

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap modals gives you a lot of flexibility in modal design and function. The "downside" to this is that you have to do a little more work yourself. If you look at the Bootstrap [modal documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) you will see that, while you are calling the modal correctly, it takes a completely different set of options than the jQuery dialog. First and foremost, you cannot pass buttons and button-actions as options to the modal. What you can do instead is create the structure you need in HTML with the buttons in place, then add javascript to control their actions. This [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7CjbpDpzdW) should work as a basic framework for what you want.